# vim join lines for matching brackets

Tags: vim

I have a tool which produces output like this -

```
(check (= Start
   (+ (if (<= takeA giveA) 0 1)
      (if (<= takeB giveB) 0 1)
      (if (<= takeC giveC) 0 1)
      (if (<= takeD giveD) 0 1))))
(check (and (>= takenBefore_A 0) (<= takenBefore_A 4)))
(check (and (>= givenBefore_A 0) (<= givenBefore_A 4)))
(check (= risk_A
   (+ Start 1 (- takenBefore_A givenBefore_A))))
(check (= takenBefore_A
   (+ (if (<= takeB takeA) 1 0)
      (if (<= takeC takeA) 1 0)
      (if (<= takeD takeA) 1 0))))
(check (= givenBefore_A
   (+ (if (<= giveA takeA) 1 0)
      (if (<= giveB takeA) 1 0)
      (if (<= giveC takeA) 1 0)
      (if (<= giveD takeA) 1 0))))
(check (and (>= takenBefore_B 0) (<= takenBefore_B 4)))
(check (and (>= givenBefore_B 0) (<= givenBefore_B 4)))
(check (= risk_B
   (+ Start 1 (- takenBefore_B givenBefore_B))))
(check (= takenBefore_B
   (+ (if (<= takeA takeB) 1 0)
      (if (<= takeC takeB) 1 0)
      (if (<= takeD takeB) 1 0))))
(check (= givenBefore_B
   (+ (if (<= giveA takeB) 1 0)
      (if (<= giveB takeB) 1 0)
      (if (<= giveC takeB) 1 0)
      (if (<= giveD takeB) 1 0))))
(check (and (>= takenBefore_C 0) (<= takenBefore_C 4)))
(check (and (>= givenBefore_C 0) (<= givenBefore_C 4)))
(check (= risk_C
   (+ Start 1 (- takenBefore_C givenBefore_C))))
```

And I would like to have the output like this -

```
(check (= Start (+ (if (<= takeA giveA) 0 1) (if (<= takeB giveB) 0 1) (if (<= takeC giveC) 0 1) (if (<= takeD giveD) 0 1))))
(check (and (>= takenBefore_A 0) (<= takenBefore_A 4)))
(check (and (>= givenBefore_A 0) (<= givenBefore_A 4)))
(check (= risk_A (+ Start 1 (- takenBefore_A givenBefore_A))))
(check (= takenBefore_A (+ (if (<= takeB takeA) 1 0) (if (<= takeC takeA) 1 0) (if (<= takeD takeA) 1 0))))
(check (= givenBefore_A (+ (if (<= giveA takeA) 1 0) (if (<= giveB takeA) 1 0) (if (<= giveC takeA) 1 0) (if (<= giveD takeA) 1 0))))
(check (and (>= takenBefore_B 0) (<= takenBefore_B 4)))
(check (and (>= givenBefore_B 0) (<= givenBefore_B 4)))
(check (= risk_B (+ Start 1 (- takenBefore_B givenBefore_B))))
(check (= takenBefore_B (+ (if (<= takeA takeB) 1 0) (if (<= takeC takeB) 1 0) (if (<= takeD takeB) 1 0))))
(check (= givenBefore_B (+ (if (<= giveA takeB) 1 0) (if (<= giveB takeB) 1 0) (if (<= giveC takeB) 1 0) (if (<= giveD takeB) 1 0))))
(check (and (>= takenBefore_C 0) (<= takenBefore_C 4)))
(check (and (>= givenBefore_C 0) (<= givenBefore_C 4)))
(check (= risk_C (+ Start 1 (- takenBefore_C givenBefore_C))))
```

I used the following command in `VIM` to produce the necessary output, depending on how many lines I want to join -

```
:.,+3join
```

I am wondering, if I can automatically do this rather than doing it manually.
The keypoint here is that, on each line the number of brackets opened will be equal to number of brackets closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My take:

```
 qqqqqv%:join
 j@qq@q
```

Using `join` instead of `J` solves the problem of single lines in Daan's answer.

Step by step:

- `qqq` to clear the 'q' macro (to avoid getting tangled with previous macro definitions)
- `q` to start recording
- `q` to state that it's the 'q' macro we're recording
- `v` for visual marking
- `%` to jump to matching brace
- `:` for command mode, acting on currently marked area
- `join` (plus ENTER) for joining the lines
- `j` to go down one line
- `@q` to call 'q' macro (recursion) (if we hadn't cleared it first, we'd be calling the old definition here, which is not what we want)
- `q` to end recording
- `@q` to execute the macro, which will stop at end-of-file (when the `j` move errors)

Excuse the abundance of `q`'s. I admit putting this on `j` would be more intuitive, but I always use `q` for fire-and-forget macros like this, because it makes the initial clear-and-record (`qqqqq`) so easy to remember (and because most other keys already have macros on them). :-)

**Edit:** Scratch that last paragraph. I just like hammering at the same key repeatedly like a madman. ;-)

Comment: Ah good catch about the `:join`! I have the following mapping: `map Q @j` and sometimes hammer QQQ myself. :)

Answer (score 3):

This would be one way to do it using a macro:

```
qjo<ESC>k0v%Jjq100@j
```

The basic idea here is that you can use `v%J` to select and join all lines in the `(...)` area. The only caveat is that it won't work for single line statements, thus we make sure to always add an extra line (`o<ESC>`). Finally we wrap it all up in a macro and it works!

Answer (score 3):

I think this `:s` line would work for you:

```
:%s/\v\n\s+(\()/\1/
```

also for the example in your question, this works too.. (but leave the 1st line empty)

```
:%j|s/(check/\r&/g
```

**EDIT**

just now i didn't put the `1d` there.  now it comes:

if you want to remove the 1st empty line, try this:

```
:%j|s/(check/\r&/g|1d
```

**EDIT2**

thanks Nikita Kouevda for pointing out the whitespace problem. also the fix (see comments below) I just neglected the space created by :join.

I would add another short line, which works too, without being worry about the spaces:

```
:g/^(/.,/\n\ze(\|\%$/j
```

Comment: Your first substitution does not get rid of redundant white-space. How ever I can overlook that because your join and substitute method is very nice.

Comment: @Peter Use `:%s/\n\s\+(/ (/` to collapse whitespace.

Comment: @Kent A negative lookbehind would avoid the empty line (e.g. `:%s/^\@<!(check/\r&/g`), but there is still trailing whitespace on every line. I believe `:%s/ \((check\)/\r\1/g` solves both issues.

Comment: the 1st line: I placed the grouping `(` at wrong place. after the `+` will skip all whitespaces. @NikitaKouevda thx. I thought pipe to `1d`. but I didn't put it there, since the point is  `j and s`. yours look-behind works too.

Comment: @NikitaKouevda just notice your whitespaces comment.... `:j` will remove spaces, unless you gave `bang[!]`

Comment: @Kent `:j` removes the original leading whitespace, but your `:s` leaves the single spaces that `:j` inserts between joined lines. Specifically, every line except for the last one now has 1 trailing space.

Comment: @NikitaKouevda ha, you are right, join leaves a space. I neglected it... it could be fixed by grouping or look-behind. Also .... by this **Join** :D http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4516

Comment: @NikitaKouevda answer updated with a new solution. thank you.

Comment: How would this fare against Windows newlines?

Answer (score 1):

If the last line of your file was blank then you  could use:

```
:g/^(/,/^(\|^$/-1j
```

which is made up of:

search for a line starting with a bracket:

```
g/^(/
```

from there to the next line starting with a bracket or an empty line

```
,/^(\|^$/
```

back to the line before that

```
-1
```

join those lines:

```
j
```

If you want to do one at a time then go to the first open bracket and v%j (enter visual, select to matching bracket, join the selected block)